# Swift: how to show a zoomed area of an UIImageView into another UIImageView

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimageview, zooming, uipangesturerecognizer

I know i have written many posts about this up to now but this could solve my problem about precision. I have seen that many app show a zoomed area of an UIImageView in the neighborhood of a draggable object like the following screenshot (Jobnote):

[image]

I would like to know which is the fastest and simplest way to get something similar. I guees the circular view is a UIImageView but I don't know hot to get the zoom inside it. Any help would be kind of yours. Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Is it possible to get this by using `MagnifierContainerView` and `MagnifyingGlassView` described [here](https://github.com/yuppielabel/YPMagnifyingGlass)?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something not too dissimilar popping up a 1:1 preview of a high resolution image which [you can read about here](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/forcezoom-popup-image-detail-view-using.html).

In a nutshell, I have a `peekPreviewSize` which is the length of the sides of my square zoomed-in preview. I can then define an offset from my touch location:

```
let offset = ((peekPreviewSize * imageScale) / (imageWidth * imageScale)) / 2
```

Next, I calculate the distance between the edge of the component and the edge of the image it contains:

```
let leftBorder = (bounds.width - (imageWidth * imageScale)) / 2
```

Then, with the location of the touch point and these two new values, I can create the normalised x origin of the clip rectangle:

```
let normalisedXPosition = ((location.x - leftBorder) / (imageWidth * imageScale)) - offset
```

I do the same for y and with those two normalised values create a preview point:

```
let topBorder = (bounds.height - (imageHeight * imageScale)) / 2
let normalisedYPosition = ((location.y - topBorder) / (imageHeight * imageScale)) - offset
let normalisedPreviewPoint = CGPoint(x: normalisedXPosition, y: normalisedYPosition)
```

...which is passed to my ForceZoomPreview:

```
let peek = ForceZoomPreview(normalisedPreviewPoint: normalisedPreviewPoint, image: image!)
```

My previewing component now has very little work to do. It's passed the normalized origin in its constructor (above), so all it needs to do is use those values to set the `contentsRect` of an image view:

```
imageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRect(
    x: max(min(normalisedPreviewPoint.x, 1), 0),
    y: max(min(normalisedPreviewPoint.y, 1), 0),
    width: view.frame.width / image.size.width,
    height: view.frame.height / image.size.height)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. I am gonna try it at once and let you know.

Comment: I am trying to run your project on xcode ios simulator but when I tap a point on the screen nothing happens. Maybe, am I using it the wrong way?

Comment: That project is powered by 3D touch Peek and Pop, so it won't work in the simulator. You'll need to tweak it to work with just a simple touch or maybe a long press recognizer. Sorry, I won't be able to access it until later today (I'm in work in the UK).

Comment: don't worry, that's ok. I guess that it won't work on iphone 4s/5/5s right?

Comment: As it stands, sadly not. But the basic mechanics will work once you remove the 3D Touch stuff.